# WPF DataGrid extended "copy and paste"

Tags: wpf, datagrid, copy, paste

How can I make the WPF DataGrid have some sort of improved "copy and paste" where I can select a single cell , copy using Ctrl-C , select a bunch of cells of columns and paste using Ctrl-V ???

So for example...in the image bellow ...I want to be able to copy the "Tech" word to all the highlighted cells just by a Ctrl-C on tech, a select of the cells, and a Ctrl-V ...

Regards,
Seb

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.261b1f3b89.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/th.261b1f3b89.jpg)

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem, did you finda any solution?

Comment: no - I was not able to find a solution in WPF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your picture is broken, so I don't know if this solves your problem exactly, but it looks promising:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/wpf-datagrid-clipboard-paste-sample)